# Crystal Reports Array with Contains in Record Selection

Tags: crystal-reports

Im attempting to do an array with a contains in my record selection from a multiple select parameter. Here is what I thought would work, what is missing here? It shows all results.

```
NumberVar i;
(for i:=1 to Ubound({?Type}) do
    (if not(hasValue({?Type})) then TRUE 
     else {?Type}[i] in {db.field})
)
```

Comment: Couldn't understood how your output should look like can you show sample

Comment: can you show us some sample data for  {?Type} and {db.field}?

Comment: also at which section have you put your formula? Details section or somewhere else?

Comment: is this your whole formula code?